# How to find min , max on array and how to change color text for min green color and max red color using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, max, min, ng-class

I have the JSON like below but I have a lot of data:

items: [
{
itemId: "22222",
category: 'A',
total: 100
},
{
itemId: "666666",
category: 'A',
total: 80
},
{
itemId: "555",
category: 'B',
total: 50
}
....
...
{
itemId: "555",
category: 'B',
total: 2
}
]

I create on `.scss`

```
   &.is-green {
      color: green;
    }
    &.is-red {
      color: red;
    }
```

I want to use it something like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items;> 
    <div>{{item.category}}</div>
    <div 
      [ngClass]="{
        'is-green': item.total ,
        'is-red':item.total
         }"
       >
       {{item.total}}</div>
    </div>
```

From this data I want to find min `total` and change color to green.
I want to find also max `total` and change color red.

Please, have you any idea how to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this question has two parts, right ?
The first one is `sorting`
and the second one is `changing the first and last items green and red`.

For Sorting, you can use this

```
items = items.sort((fstItem, secItem)=> fstItem.total > secItem.total ? 1 :
fstItem.total < secItem.total -1 : 0 );
```

for second thing, you can use in html with first and last index from [*ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; first as isFirstItem; last as isLastItem;"> 
  <div>{{item.category}}</div>
  <div [ngClass]="{'is-green': isFirstItem,
                   'is-red': isLastItem
                    }">
   {{item.total}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also get the min and max value (using reduce or a simple loop) and use some like: `[style.background]=item.total==minValue?'green':item.total==maxValue?'red':null`

Comment: Thank you, It's works good. If I have more value, for example items: [ { itemId: "22222", category: 'A', total: 100, price:20 }, { itemId: "666666", category: 'A', total: 80 ,price:25}, { itemId: "555", category: 'B', total: 50,price:20 } .... ... { itemId: "555", category: 'B', total: 2 ,price:21} ]` How to sorting `total` and `price` ?

Comment: According to your priority, you have to sort twice. Sort with total and then sort with price or the other way.

Comment: hmm, I found a problem on it, I want to color min and max total. This solution color only first item on array and last item on array. Can you change it please?

Comment: the first and last items are not minimum and maximum according to your array ?